# How to connect both S3 and SNS with Spring boot? (com.amazonaws.transform.Unmarshaller error)

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sns

In my application I need to use both S3 and SNS of AWS. I was using S3 without problem but now I have added SNS dependency as well as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.141</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.319</version>
        </dependency>
```

But When I try to subscribe to a topic of SNS:

```
@GetMapping("/addSubscription/{email}")
    public String addSubscription(@PathVariable String email) {
        SubscribeRequest request = new SubscribeRequest(TOPIC_ARN, "email", email);
        snsClient.subscribe(request); //ERROR COMES HERE
        return "Subscription request is pending. To confirm the subscription, check your email : " + email;
    }
```

I get the Error:

```
2022-10-31 19:56:54.354 ERROR 41464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.a.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler   : Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.amazonaws.http.DefaultErrorResponseHandler.<init>(java.util.Map, com.amazonaws.transform.Unmarshaller)'
```

I have checked some similar questions and people generally mention the aws sdk version but in their example only 1 service is used but I need both S3 and SNS. How can I use both of them ?

Comment: Something might be pulling in a conflicting version of one of the AWS libraries. Run the maven command `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.amazonaws` and include the output in your question.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` is almost always due to version mismatch between build and execution environments.  You invoke a method that is present in your dependencies in the build environment, but that method is not present in your execution environment.

Comment: While I agree with @smac2020 below if you can't convert to the V2 libraries right now **at least** keep the same version between S3 and SNS.  I generally have a property that declares the version of the AWS SDK libraries I'm using and all libraries move to a new version at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the AWS SDK for Java V1. This is not best practice at all. You should be using AWS SDK for Java V2.

It appears you are looking to use SNS with Spring BOOT. If you look at the AWS COde Lib, you will find that exact use case here:

[image]

The URL is

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sns_example_cross_SnsPublishSubscription_section.html

To find the most recent code examples for the AWS SDK, always refer to this Code Library.

(Click the Java tab).

**UPDATE**

I just ran this Spring BOOT app that uses A**WS SDK for Java V2** and it works perfectly....

[image]

Comment: in code example it is using sns dependency from software.amazon.awssdk. but this dependency is not resolved

Comment: You need to build the sample app with the POM file listed in GITHUB here. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_sns_sample_app